# Is it acceptable to have the USB C cable overmold not touching the enclosure?

Tags: usb

In my current design iteration, I flushed the USB C receptacle to the enclosure, such that when a USB C cable is connected, the overmold is not touching the enclosure and there is about a 1.85mm margin between the enclosure and the overmold. Is this acceptable?

I looked through the USB C specs and only saw a specification stating that the overmold and the enclosure needs to have a margin of at least 0.05mm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's much less robust than it usually is (which is to say, so-so). Is that one of the very shallow/short connectors? You might consider a full length one next time, which will distribute forces better over the PCB.  Also prefer THT types if possible; SMT adhesion is not that great.